# Recipients are not showing in email screen in Android

Tags: android, email

Hi I am using in built email sending functionality.But when I tried the code.

```
void sendEmailMessage(String emailId)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "emailId = "+emailId);
        Intent intentEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intentEmail.setType("text/plain");
        String[] recipients = new String[]{emailId};

        intentEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,recipients);
        intentEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
        intentEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body of email");
        try
        {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentEmail, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I don't see recipient email address in recipient EditText on Email screen.I am not getting what I am doing wrong please help.

Comment: I think in your `void sendEmailMessage(String emailId)` method's `emailId` argument didn't have the value. Just check where you've been called from. And, make sure you are passing email id or not? Post the full code.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your `void sendEmailMessage(String emailId)` method's `emailId` argument didn't have the value. Just check where you've been called from. And, make sure you are passing email id or not? For example. In your class's somewhere just call that method like below with value.

```
sendEmailMessage("mail@mail.com");
```

Comment: No I am passing proper emailId to method.